# pset 5 speller, turning frowns upside down, programme can't handle most basic words or chars

Tags: c, hashtable, cs50

the task is to create a fully functioning spell check, I think I have more than one error in my code which is causing lots of difficulty when trying to wrap my head round what exactly is causing all the frowns on check50. check50 only says my code compiles, everything else is a frown, I think my programme could be exiting during the check function as size and unload have no runtime. I also get exit code 1 once run, however I may be wayyy off as this is my first programming course. Any tips, help or pointers in the right direction would be massivly appriciated!

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}       node;

// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 1000;

// Hash table

 node *table[N];

bool check(const char *word)
{   

// hash word
int x = hash(word);
// create cursor, set to first item in linked list
node *cursor = table[x];
// loop over hash tables
while (cursor != NULL)
{
    if (strcasecmp(word, cursor->word) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    cursor = cursor->next;
}

return false;
}

int dictionary_size = 0; // global variable for size of dictionary, used in multiple   functions

  unsigned int hash(const char *word)
 {
  int value = 0;

// hash function using math of all leters

// loop over every word

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
{
    // convert to lower case for ascii values, removes case sensitive problem

    value += tolower(word[i]); // sum of ascii values of word
}

return value % N; // return index for word
 }

  // Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false

  bool load(const char *dictionary)
  {
// TODO

// array to store words from dictionary

char word[LENGTH + 1];

// open dictionary file

FILE *d = fopen(dictionary, "r");
if (d == NULL)
{
    return false;
}

// read strings from file repeat for each word in dictionary , similar loop to       recover.c


while (fscanf(d, "%s", word) != EOF)

{
    // keep track of dictionary size

    dictionary_size++;

    // create new node

    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (n == NULL)
    {

        return false;
    }

    // store word in array

    strcpy(n->word, word);
    n->next = NULL;

    // hash word

    int x = hash(word);

    // set pointers to correct order

    n->next = table[x];
    table[x] = n;
}

fclose(d);
return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded, else 0 if not yet loaded

   unsigned int size(void)
{

return dictionary_size;
}

  // Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful, else false

    bool unload(void)
   {

// loop over hash tables
for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
{
    // initialise cursor for local scope

    node *cursor = table[j];

    // traverse linked list

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        node *tmp = cursor;
        cursor = cursor->next;
        free(tmp);
        return true;
     }
  }
   return false;
  }
```

Comment: There is no `main` function.

Comment: apologies, i forgot to say that it is compiled using make speller, this is a part of the speller programme that is called dictionary.c

Comment: One thing I will say is that you are writing code that is difficult to read. Paying attention to the indentation and formatting will pay off in the long run, and many code editors can help with this.

Comment: ok thanks I'll keep that in mind when continuing with this course

Comment: It makes no difference to the compiler but it's a disincentive to look through the code.

Comment: We can't see any frownies. You will need to tell us what is wrong with your code. And what your code is intented to do.

Comment: What happens when you try to run it locally? Or in a debugger?

Comment: The hint regarding indentation is not just meant for your course. It is also relevant for this question. Please edit to apply proper indentation making the code way more readable.

Comment: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2022/psets/5/speller/   this is a link to an expilnation of what my code is attempting to solve, it will explain it way better than I can, in regards to the frowns the only one i have now is: :( programme is free of memory errors. check50 was saying everything was wrong, could've been an error with it

Comment: will rerun it on the debugger now check50 seems to be working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments:

> *in regards to the frowns the only one i have now is: :( programme is free of memory errors. check50 was saying everything was wrong, could've been an error with it*

The `unload` function frees one node and then `return`s (to the call from speller). The function should not return until it has freed all the nodes (ie finished the while loop).